# Cart page Producrs

Tags: magento2, cart, products

I am add new products but the user in cart page can change country i want the user can not change country in cart page how can I disable this ? Can not the user change country?

Please give me response about this

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps,

||Go to the Magento admin panel and navigate to **Stores > Configuration.**

||Expand the **General** section and select **General**.

||In the **Country Options** section, set **Allow Countries** to the specific country or
countries that you want to allow for shipping.

||Save the configuration and refresh the cache if necessary.

||By setting the **Allow Countries** option, users will only be able to select countries that are enabled for shipping. If you only enable one country, then the user will not be able to change the country in the cart page. If you enable multiple countries, then the user will only be able to select from the allowed countries.

Another way

Identify the code that controls the country selection in the cart page. This could be a form element or a dropdown menu.

Add a condition to the code that checks whether the user has already added products to their cart. If the user has added products to their cart, the country selection element should be disabled or hidden.

Test the changes to make sure that users can no longer change the country selection once they have added products to their cart.

Your code might look something like this,

```
if (cartHasProducts()) {
  
  document.getElementById('country-selector').disabled = true;
}
```

Try this I hope this resolve that issue

Comment: Merge your answer into one please.